# Most performant way to compare first 2 bytes (given a pointer) to fixed values?

Tags: c, memcmp

Given a pointer I want to compare the first two bytes to fixed values.
`data` is a void pointer.
Is there a "better" way than this:

```
unsigned char foo[] = {0xFF, 0x3B};
memcmp(data, foo, 2);
```

Maybe where I dont have to create a new char array?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you profiled to assume that that is the bottleneck in your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should certainly *try* doing it using `memcmp()`, but if that creates overhead you can do it like [@LS_dev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19134061/28169) suggested, although I would suggest doing explicit character accesses to avoid the endianness issue:

```
if(((unsigned char *) data)[0] == 0xff && ((unsigned char *) data)[1] == 0x3b)
{
}
```

of course, it would make sense to factor out the casting for a major clarity boost:

```
const unsigned char *chardata = data;
if(chardata[0] == 0xff && chardata[1] == 0x3b)
{
}
```

Comment: +1 I thought about this also, but although safer, implies more operations.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Due to some concerns regarding `sizeof(char)`, memory alignment and compiler/library optimizations,

As a **PLATFORM DEPENDENT** alternative, this answer **MAY HAVE** better performance then `memcmp`:

Little endian (Intel byte-order):

```
if (*(short*)foo == 0x3bff) ...
```

Big endian (Network byte order):

```
if (*(short*)foo == 0xff3b) ...
```

Comment: @redx: Nop, but avoiding a function call seams a big gain to me!

Comment: memcmp should be inlined with optimizations on.

Comment: I suppose so. But compiler should also optimize this comparison.

Comment: `memcmp` can be used to compare smallest possible types (`char`), so it must do comparison in a manner where alignment is not an issue.

Comment: No, memcmp will not have this problem. You have to maintain 2 lines of code depending on the architecture you're running on. And this code is not portable at all: you're assuming `char` is 8 bits which is not guaranteed.

Comment: @fjardon Also a good point. Added a <i>advice</i> clause in answer!